# Build .NET Core app offline from a build server

Tags: .net, .net-core, build

I'm trying to build a .NET Core 3.1 application from a build server that does not have connectivity to nuget.org. The build is failing due to missing packages that are not being referenced directly by my project (e.g., Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Microsoft.Extensions.Options, System.Runtime.Loader). I had the same problem with .NET Core 2.2, but worked around it by utilizing the NugetFallbackFolder that was installed with the 2.2 SDK. Versions 3.0 and above the SDK have done away with the NugetFallbackFolder.

Given that, how does one go about building a .NET Core app disconnected from nuget.org? I've scoured the internet and have found nothing.

Comment: You will need access to nuget.org. You could download all the nuget packages you think your application needs and put them on-disk locally on the machine that's disconnected from the internet.

Comment: That feels like a huge oversight on Microsoft's part. Considering how many NuGet packages make up .NET Core, downloading them individually for every Core release is not feasible. The frustrating part is that the libraries dotnet.exe is complaining about not being able to resolve are ones that are not directly referenced, so it is difficult to even know what to grab.